# allocate dynamic memory for char array

Tags: c, malloc, structure

I have to print some values stored in the struct to single char array , I am not getting an simple method to allocate a memory for a variable array values .

below snnipet of the code which I need to do

```
 struct types {

char *name;
char *address;
char * descrption;
};

int main ()
{

  int numberofUser = 10;

  struct types allUsers[numberofUser];

  //Assume here I filled all the user details by allocation memory.

  // now I need to print these values in the formated string like below


 char* outputString;

 int i ;
 for(i =0 ; i<numberofUser;i++)
 {
 sprintf(outputString,"<start>name=%s,add=%s,des=%s",allUsers[i].name,allUsers[i].address,allUsers[i].descrption);
 }
}
```

How to allocate memory for the output string which can hold all structure values

Comment: Your code writes all users into the start of the string (so later users overwrite the earlier ones). Is this what you want, or is there meant to be concatenation happening?

Comment: `malloc()`... You need to allocate number of elements times `sizeof(element)`. just read the documentation.

Comment: numberofUser must be of type "const int"

Comment: What are you going to do with the output string once it is fully populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define the format string and store it in a variable of its own.

   ```
   char const* formatString = "<start>name=%s,add=%s,des=%s";
   ```
2. Get the length of the format string.

   ```
   size_t formatStringLen = strlen(formatString);
   ```
3. Get the lengths of the members of the struct.

   ```
   size_t nameLen = strlen(allUser[i].name);
   size_t addLen = strlen(allUser[i].address);
   size_t desLen = strlen(allUser[i].description);
   ```
4. Allocate enough memory to hold the format string as well as the members of the struct.

   ```
   // This will be more than the exact space you need but certainly
   // not less than what you need and not too much more than what you
   // need.
   size_t totalLen = formatStringLen + nameLen + addLen + desLen;
   outputString = malloc(totalLen);
   ```
5. Use `sprintf`

   ```
    sprintf(outputString, formatString,
            allUsers[i].name, allUsers[i].address, allUsers[i].descrption);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate length of strings involved and allocate that much memory to it. Something like

```
int len = 0;

len = strlen(allUsers[i].name) 
      + strlen(allUsers[i].address) 
      + strlen(allUsers[i].descrption);
len += strlen("<start>name=") 
     + strlen(",add=") 
     + strlen(",des=");
len ++ // for '\0'

outputString = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
```

Note: this is for 1 record in `allUsers` as strings may change in other elements.

You should check for valid pointers and should free memory after used.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports C99 then it shall contain function `snprintf`. To allocate and set your string, you can use the following code:

```
char *outputString;
int  len;
outputString = NULL;
len = 0;
for(;;) {
    // this loop is executed only two times
    len = 1 + snprintf(outputString, len, "<start>name=%s,add=%s,des=%s",allUsers[i].name,allUsers[i].address,allUsers[i].descrption);
    if (outputString != NULL) break;                  // success
    outputString = realloc(outputString, len);
    if (outputString == NULL) break;                  // fail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The members of your structure are pointers to characters, i.e. of type `char *` but you need a character array to store the strings. The size of the array must be one more than the maximum length the string can have to accommodate the terminating null byte which marks the end of the string. I suggest the following changes -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAMELEN 20+1  // max length of name + 1
#define ADDRLEN 40+1  // max length of address + 1
#define DESCLEN 80+1  // max length of description + 1

struct types {
    char name[NAMELEN];
    char address[ADDRLEN];
    char descrption[DESCLEN];
};

int main(void) {
    int numberofUser = 10;
    struct types allUsers[numberofUser];

    // assign values to array elements        

    // format string for sprintf
    const char *fstr = "<start>name=%s,add=%s,des=%s";

    // strlen doesn't count the null byte. macros include null byte
    // so get space for 2 extra null bytes which is not needed.
    int outlen = strlen(fstr) + NAMELEN + ADDRLEN + DESCLEN - 2;

    // variable-length to store the output string
    char outputString[outlen];

    for(int i = 0; i < numberofUser; i++) {
        sprintf(outputString, "<start>name=%s,add=%s,des=%s",
                allUsers[i].name,
                allUsers[i].address,
                allUsers[i].descrption);

        // print the string
        printf("%s\n", outputString); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this looks like good, but how will I reallocate the "outputString" , to hold all the structure values ...in my example I have to fill all stucture allUsers[10], values in to single string